# Impliment cron script in yii2 rest api

Tags: cron, yii2

i am using Advance Api template in yii2 . i need cron script which call

Api but i dont know how to performed cron script in yii2 . can any one help me?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/646/how-to-implement-cron-in-yii-2/

Answer (score 1):

create a console command as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html).
Then register your cron script like:

```
php yii mycontroller/myaction
```